# Angular Material Autocomplete using template driven form error, data won't show

Tags: angular, debugging, error-handling, angular-material, autocomplete

So have a problem here implementing filter autocomplete in angular material inside standalone component. But, instead of using Form Control, i use template drive form ([ngModel]). Actually, the data is already shown in console, but in the autocomplete display, the data won't showed. I have already debugged this for a day but i'm already very overwhelmed because it seems i just stuck here all day. I hope you guys can help me.

Below is my template code.

```
<div class="flex flex-col mb-[12px]">
      <label for="user.report_to_user" class="text-[10px] font-normal">*Report To User</label>
      <input 
            [(ngModel)]="formData.data.reportToUser" 
            (ngModelChange)="onInputChange()" 
            type="text" 
            name="user.report_to_user" 
            placeholder="Report To User" 
            class="input-form" 
            [matAutocomplete]="auto" 
            required>
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayOption">
               <option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [value]="option">
                  {{ option.desc }}
               </option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
            <div 
                *ngIf="formData.data.reportToUser == ''" 
                class="text-[10px] text-red-600 justify-start">
                    {{ requiredValidation }}
            </div>
</div>
```

this is my component code.

```
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatAccordion, MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatIcon, MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {FormsModule, FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AuthService} from '../../../../services/user-management/auth/auth.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

export interface UserLookUpResponse {
    data: UserLookUp[];
    IsSuccess: boolean;
    Message: string;
    IsApproval: boolean;
    ReturnId: number;
}

export interface UserLookUp {
    id: string,
    desc: string
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-create-user-form',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatIconModule,
        FormsModule,
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    templateUrl: './create-user-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./create-user-form.component.css']
})
export class CreateUserFormComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private ref : MatDialogRef<CreateUserFormComponent>,
        private authService : AuthService
    ) {}

    options: UserLookUp[] = [];
    filteredOptions: UserLookUp[] = this.options;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.fetchUserLookUp();
    }

    onInputChange() {
        const value = this
            .formData
            .data
            .reportToUser
            .toLowerCase();
        console.log(value);
        this.filteredOptions = this
            .options
            .filter(option => option['desc'].toLowerCase().includes(value));
        console.log(this.filteredOptions);
    }

    formData = {
        data: {
            userInfo: {
                username: '',
                first_name: '',
                last_name: '',
                email: '',
                password: '',
                job_title: '',
                is_user_active: true,
                is_user_locked: false,
                department: '',
                office_address: '',
                office_country: ''
            },
            reportToUser: '',
            reportToTeam: 'Default'
        }
    };

    randomPass: string = '';
    showGeneratedPassword: boolean = false;
    passwordError: string = '';
    isButtonDisabled: boolean = false;
    requiredValidation: string = 'This field is required' @ViewChild(MatAccordion)accordion !: MatAccordion;

    closePopup() {
        this
            .ref
            .close('Closed using function')
    };

    onSelectChange(event : Event): void {
        const target = event.target as HTMLSelectElement;
        const selectedValue = target.value;

        if (selectedValue === 'generate') {
            this.generatePassword();
        } else {
            this.randomPass = '';
            this.showGeneratedPassword = false;
        }
    };

    fetchUserLookUp() {
        this
            .authService
            .getLookUpUser()
            .subscribe((user) => {
                this.options = user.data;
                console.log('Options:', this.options);
            })
    }

    displayOption(option : UserLookUp) {
        console.log("ini yang di display", option);
        return option
            ? option.desc
            : 'undefined';
    }
```

and this is my service code to get the data inside the seperated file, auth.service.ts

```
getLookUpUser(): Observable<any> {
    let token = this.utils.getToken()
      const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        })
      };
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/User/GetUserLookup`, httpOptions)
  }
```

i need your help guys, thank you!

i already tried to change the displayOption and i already tried to do everything they told inside the angular material documentation, but it seems i didn't get any revelation.